# Split string by known substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a list of different strings (this is an example):

```
strs = ["FOOBAR", "PYTHON", "MAPARTS"]
```

and I've got another list with substrings that one of the strings in the previous list might contain:

```
substrs = ["ARTS", "FOO", "PY", "BAR", "MAP"]
```

I want to make a list that has all the strings in `strs` that can be split  using two strings in `substrs`, split by them and wrapped in a list or tuple. So the finished list would look like:

```
[("FOO", "BAR"), ("MAP", "ARTS")]
```

I can't wrap my head around how to manage it, at least in a simple way. Any help?

Comment: Seems like a double loop task. From missing `python` in results, I assume it always has to be a full composition?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an interesting approach if you want to check if any combination of two `tokens` is a word listed in `words`:

```py
from itertools import product

words = ["FOOBAR", "PYTHON", "MAPARTS"]

tokens = ["ARTS", "FOO", "PY", "BAR", "MAP"]

pairs = [_ for _ in product(tokens, tokens) if ''.join(_) in words]
```

Resulting in:

```py
>>> pairs
[('FOO', 'BAR'), ('MAP', 'ARTS')]
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach would probably be to loop through the list of substrings. For each value in `substrs`, keep track (with your finished list) of whether prepending it to each of the other substrings results in a value that exists in `strs`.

```
finished = []
substrs = ["ARTS", "FOO", "PY", "BAR", "MAP"]
strs = ["FOOBAR", "PYTHON", "MAPARTS"]

for sub1 in substrs:
  for sub2 in substrs:
    combined = sub1 + sub2
    if combined in strs: finished.append((sub1, sub2))
```

There may be a more efficient algorithm, but this approach was the easiest way for me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**using itertools.permutations** - >

```
import itertools
result = [
    item
    for item in itertools.permutations(substrs, 2)
    if ''.join(item) in strs
]
```

Here, the idea is to take all the permutation of length 2 and then join and check if that's available in 1st list or not